# @Queryの処理について

Tags: java, spring

下記のコードですが、ManagementEntity型のListの変数 `selectBysp_cdForUpdate` に `sp_cdList` を引数として渡している。
というコードだと思うのですが、`@Query` が `public List<ManagementEntity> selectBysp_cdForUpdate(List<String> sp_cdList);` に対して何をしているのかが分からないため、教えていただきたいです。

```
@Query(value = "select * from shop_no"
        + " where sp_cdin ?1"
        + " for update", nativeQuery = true)
public List<ManagementEntity> selectBysp_cdForUpdate(List<String> sp_cdList);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`selectBysp_cdForUpdate`の第1引数である`sp_cdList`の値が`?1`に代入されるような形で、最終的にSQLが発行されます。

`?1` はプレースフォルダと呼ばれるものです。

このあたりが参考になると思います。
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-query#1-jpql-2
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-query#2-native-2

ご質問者のコードには `nativeQuery = true` が記載されているので、上記リンクの２つ目のものですね。

ということで

> @Queryがpublic List selectBysp_cdForUpdate(List sp_cdList);に対して何をしているのかが、わからないです。

`@Query`が`selectBysp_cdForUpdate`メソッドに対して何かしていると考えるより、逆の`selectBysp_cdForUpdate`メソッドが`@Query`の文に何かしている（今回の場合は`?1`を置き換えている）と考えたほうがわかりやすいでしょう。